# How to refactor to avoid F# Lint's warning?

Tags: f#

I have the following nested Seq.map() calls in a function that compiles and works effectively:

```
|> Seq.map (fun (tradedOnKey : DateTime, portfolioSeq : seq<PortfolioId * seq<PortfolioFundRecord>>) ->
        let pricedPortfoliosGroup = 
            portfolioSeq 
            |> Seq.map (fun (p : PortfolioId, spsf : (seq<PortfolioFundRecord>)) ->
                let price = 
                    spsf 
                    |> Seq.map (fun (pfr : PortfolioFundRecord) -> pfr.Fund.ClosingPrice * float pfr.PortfolioWeight / 100.0) 
                    |> Seq.reduce (+)
                let topPortfolioFundRecord = spsf |> Seq.head
                { PortfolioId = p; Price = price; TradedOn = topPortfolioFundRecord.Fund.TradedOn }
            )
        (tradedOnKey, pricedPortfoliosGroup)
)
```

which prompts the following lint warning:

> Lint: `Seq.map f (Seq.map g x)` might be able to be refactored into `Seq.map (g >>f) x`.

I believe the warning is prompted by these top 2 map calls:

```
|> Seq.map (fun (tradedOnKey : DateTime, portfolioSeq : seq<PortfolioId * seq<PortfolioFundRecord>>) ->
        let pricedPortfoliosGroup = 
            portfolioSeq 
            |> Seq.map (fun (p : PortfolioId, spsf : (seq<PortfolioFundRecord>)) ->
```

but I don't know how to refactor them since my 2nd parameter is a sequence and I want to "transform it" but not flatten it.

Can you suggest a way to do that? I also looked for a way to turn off the lint warning just for that code fragment but the power tools do not seem to offer a way to do that.

Here's the whole function for completeness sake:

```
let getPortfoliosPrices(dbFundsWithPortfolioFunds : (DbFunds * DbPortfolioFunds) Linq.IQueryable)(takenDays: int) =

let portfolioPrices =
    dbFundsWithPortfolioFunds
    |> Seq.collect(fun (f : DbFunds, fp : DbPortfolioFunds) -> 
        takenDays |> getStockPrices f.Symbol
        |> Seq.map(fun(quote : FundQuote) -> 
            let portfolioFundRec = {PortfolioId = fp.PortfolioId; PortfolioWeight = fp.Weight; Fund = quote}
            portfolioFundRec)
        )
        |> Seq.groupBy(fun (portfolioFundRec : PortfolioFundRecord) -> portfolioFundRec.Fund.TradedOn)
        |> Seq.map(fun (tradedOnKey : DateTime, spfr : PortfolioFundRecord seq) -> 
        let gpfr = spfr |> Seq.groupBy (fun(pfr : PortfolioFundRecord)->pfr.PortfolioId)
        (tradedOnKey, gpfr)
    )
    |> Seq.map (fun (tradedOnKey : DateTime, portfolioSeq : seq<PortfolioId * seq<PortfolioFundRecord>>) ->
            let pricedPortfoliosGroup = 
                portfolioSeq 
                |> Seq.map (fun (p : PortfolioId, spsf : (seq<PortfolioFundRecord>)) ->
                    let price = 
                        spsf 
                        |> Seq.map (fun (pfr : PortfolioFundRecord) -> pfr.Fund.ClosingPrice * float pfr.PortfolioWeight / 100.0) 
                        |> Seq.reduce (+)
                    let topPortfolioFundRecord = spsf |> Seq.head
                    { PortfolioId = p; Price = price; TradedOn = topPortfolioFundRecord.Fund.TradedOn }
                )
            (tradedOnKey, pricedPortfoliosGroup)
    )
portfolioPrices
```

Comment: The warning is not about nested map calls, it's about a sequence of map calls. No idea where that happens in your code, maybe at that place where you do map - groupBy - map, in which case it's probably just bad advice.

Comment: Slightly off topic, but is there a specific reason why you are writing that many type annotations? I would expect you can remove 90% of them and get much more readable code.

Comment: @Anton To aid getting up to speed with the shape of the intermediate results over the function's lifetime maintenance. Some advocate interjecting intermediate map-> "breakpoint" or printfn functions but that may clutter too. As a style, I was also mentored to type annotate as much as a form of documentation. I understand this may not be a popular choice with everyone.

Comment: @scrwtp the second and third `map`s pipe into each (not clear at a first glance)

Comment: @MatthewMcveigh: Thanks, I see it now... It shows that there's a problem with how dense this code is, and that's far more important than two maps in a row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your second top-level `Seq.map`, you are just passing `tradedOnKey` through, and do something with your sequence. You could merge all that into one, by doing:

```
dbFundsWithPortfolioFunds
|> Seq.collect(fun (f : DbFunds, fp : DbPortfolioFunds) -> 
    takenDays |> getStockPrices f.Symbol
    |> Seq.map(fun(quote : FundQuote) -> 
        let portfolioFundRec = {PortfolioId = fp.PortfolioId; PortfolioWeight = fp.Weight; Fund = quote}
        portfolioFundRec)
    )
    |> Seq.groupBy(fun portfolioFundRec-> portfolioFundRec.Fund.TradedOn)
    |> Seq.map(fun (tradedOnKey, spfr) -> 
        let gpfr = spfr |> Seq.groupBy (fun pfr -> pfr.PortfolioId)
        let pricedPortfoliosGroup = 
            gpfr
            |> Seq.map (fun (p, spsf) ->
                let price = 
                    spsf 
                    |> Seq.sumBy (fun pfr -> pfr.Fund.ClosingPrice * float pfr.PortfolioWeight / 100.0) 
                let topPortfolioFundRecord = spsf |> Seq.head
                { PortfolioId = p; Price = price; TradedOn = topPortfolioFundRecord.Fund.TradedOn }
            )
        (tradedOnKey, pricedPortfoliosGroup)
)
```

This should get rid of the warning (difficult to verify because I don't have all the type definitions for a full repro).

Comment: That's it! And thanks for the sumBy optimization. There's a typo in that same line: pfr instead of pdr.